# Dynamically setting values for twitter configuration Mulesoft

Tags: mule

Using mulesoft twitter connector an dynamically setting values for the twitter config parameters as shown below,

```
<twitter:config name="Twitter__Configuration" accessKey="#[flowVars.accessToken]"  consumerKey="#[flowVars.consumerKey]"       consumerSecret="#[flowVars.consumerSecret]" doc:name="Twitter: Configuration" accessSecret="#[flowVars.accessTokenSecret]"/>
<flow name="twitterFlow1">
    <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from twittercredentials;]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
    <set-variable variableName="consumerKey" value="#[message.payload[0]['consumerkey']]" doc:name="Variable" />
    <set-variable variableName="consumerSecret" value="#[message.payload[0]['consumersecret']]" doc:name="Variable" />
    <set-variable variableName="accessToken" value="#[message.payload[0]['accesstoken']]" doc:name="Variable" />
    <set-variable variableName="accessTokenSecret" value="#[message.payload[0]['accesstokensecret']]" doc:name="Variable" />
</flow>
<flow name="twitterFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/twitterconnect" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <flow-ref name="twitterFlow1" />
    <twitter:show-user config-ref="Twitter__Configuration" doc:name="Twitter"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>
```

But I get an exception when invoking /twitterconnect,

```
 Failed to connect/reconnect: Work Descriptor. Root Exception was: 401 response received, but no WWW-Authenticate header was p
 resent. Type: class java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Works fine with hard coded values in the twitter config. Any help please?

Comment: If you place a logger before the Twitter flow reference (or before Twitter), are the key, secret, and token in the payload as an array?  First thing I would check is to make sure the data is being sent.  Also if it's an object verses an array, you might need to change to payload.consumerKey instead of payload[0].consumerKey

Comment: If I place logger for message.payload  before twitter:show-user command, the values are as , [{accesstoken=xxx accesstokensecret=xxx, consumersecret=xx,  consumerkey=xxx}]

Answer (score 0):

I think that won't work because you instance the twitter:config only one time and is empty.
You should find the way to create a new configuration and inject it to the twitter component.

Comment: Thanks @Federico Barrera Oro , could you please advise on how to proceed with this one? Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
Create a properties file and write the AccessKey, AccessSecret, ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret values in the properties file with references, and enter the details in the twitter connector as ${} and place the references inside the braces.